# How can I pass an optional flag to a dependency of my npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm working on an npm package, let's call it `foo`, that has a few external dependencies. One such dependency, `bar` requires a build flag in order to work with my project. If I were to manually install the dependencies I would say:

`npm install bar --bar-option=1
 ... # other deps
 npm install foo
 node script_that_uses_foo.js`

I would like the dependencies of `foo` to be installed automatically with `npm install foo`. So I have a section in my `package.json` file that looks like this:

  `"dependencies" : {
    "bar": "file:../../bar-0.1.0.tgz",
    "baz": "*"
  }`

This works fine, except that `bar` is installed without `--bar-option=1`. How can I tell `npm` to pass this argument to the install script of `bar`? I've looked through the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) and haven't found what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is really old, but I believe that in this case, you can

```
    npm install foo --bar-option=1
```

npm will pass bar-option through to all dependencies, e.g. "bar" when installing them.

alternatively, inside of foo's package.json, you could define a preinstall script that does "npm install bar --bar-option=1"