# Passing an argument through package.json to installation script of npm package dependency

Tags: javascript, npm

I have an npm package that configures itself for one of three target platforms when it is being installed as a  (node.js, browser, react-native). Or at least this is my goal, right now it always configures itself for node.js because I have not found a way to give it the desired information.

The solutions that came to my mind have the disadvantage that the developer adding the package dependency has to do something, for example, I could ask them to set an environment variable, which would have to be done each time someone installs or updates modules.

What I would really like is a way to send a parameter to the installation script of the npm module, and that parameter ideally is in `package.json`, double-ideally in the actual line that configures the dependency on this package.

I found [this similar question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516338/how-can-i-pass-an-optional-flag-to-a-dependency-of-my-npm-package) - but it has no answer, not even a single comment.

I checked the npm documentation but didn't find anything. I can only think of workarounds outside npm. It makes me wonder if I'm doing something wrong with what I'm looking for, or if I'm overlooking something, because it seems to me that this should be if not a common than at least not an extremely rare question? I can't imagine that npm modules configuring themselves to different environments through their installation script in not 100% automatable ways that depend on a provided parameter should be so rare that there aren't even any questions about it. Yet I found none, only discussions about passing parameters to scripts defined in `package.json`.

Comment: Could you describe what parameter you are trying to use in the install script?

Comment: As I said, the install. script configures the package. It needs a parameter that tells it which platform to configure it for, node.js, browser or react-native. If called on the command line one would use command line options passed to the command.

Comment: And if the project using this package wants a different "configuration" after they chose one? What do they do? Uninstall, change the parameter and install again? Why not ship all 3 configurations and let the users choose what to "require"/"import"? Like `require('your-package/react-native')` or `require('your-package/browser')`. Or the package should detect the runtime environment and act accordingly.

Comment: @Strelok It will be a frequent occurrence that somebody starts a project for a given system (node.js, browser, etc). It will be exceedingly rare that they switch their target platform. And if, they just call the configuration script manually. *"Or the package should detect the runtime environment "* -- I don't care about the runtime environment of the development system! And I don't know what their target platform is. How do you tell from inside an npm package what platform the person using your package is developing for, browser or node.js or react-native?

Comment: Well there are ways to detect if JS code is running in browser or node or react native. Isomorphic JS packages do it all the time. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @strelok Does the developer run their IDE and development environment inside a browser (and if they did, using a browser-based IDE, how do I know that that is where the actual app will run)? Does the npm package installation run in the browser? Or don't people develop in a different environment compared to where their apps run? I'm asking about what I described, installing an npm package. npm packages are not installed into the running app but into the development environment.

Comment: Bottom line is there is no way to pass any flags to install script of a dependency via package.json so you have to come up with another solution.